# Problem with id_product_attribute in URLs

Tags: prestashop

I have a PrestaShop shop with a module for clean id from category urls. My url format for products is "{rewrite}-{id}.html" so PS add "?id_product_attibute=0" on all my products. I want to remove it or put my url format like "{rewrite}-{id}{-:id_product_attribute}.html"
I'm ussing https://github.com/faktiva/prestashop-clean-urls

Comment: Hi there! Why do you want to change the URL format? Can you provide an example of a URL your products already has, and an example of what you want it to look like? Cheers.

Comment: I really dont like my actual url. My actual url is: http://www.myshop.com/shoes-black-29.html?id_product_attribute=0. I dont like "?id_product_attribute". I want to have my url like http://www.myshop.com/shoes-black-29-0.html or only http://www.myshop.com/shoes-black-29.html

Comment: By doing this, your store will have multiple urls with the same content and will cause a negative SEO score

Comment: The urls look like you're using PS 1.7? If so faktivas clean urls module will unfortunately **not** work (like it says in the first line of the readme...)

Answer (score 1):

The id_product_attribute can be removed from the Product URL without changing in the SEO configuration in the back-office.

You can override the **`getProductLink()`** function of the **Link.php** class or make changes in the CORE file.

Remove or comment the **`$params['id_product_attribute'] = $ipa;`** from line number 156 in the above function.